# Python merge two csv files python

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 CSV files.

**File1.csv**

```
    Frame_Nr; Data1; Data2; Labeled
    0          0       1        1
    1          0       0        1
    2          1       1        1
    3          0       0        0
    4          0       0        0
    5          1       0        1
    6          0       0        0
    7          0       0        0
   11          0       1        1
   12          1       1        1
```

**File2.csv**

```
Frame_Nr; Data1; Data2; Labeled
    0          0       0        0
    1          0       0        0
    2          0       0        0
    3          0       0        0
    4          0       0        0
    5          0       0        0
    6          0       0        0
    7          0       0        0
    8          0       0        0
    9          0       0        0
   10          0       0        0
```

I want the output to look something like this. And should merge **file2.csv** with file **file1.csv** and if there are some changes to replace with data from **file1.csv** else to keep data from **file2.csv**

Expected **output.csv**

```
    Frame_Nr; Data1; Data2; Labeled
    0          0       1        1
    1          0       0        1
    2          1       1        1
    3          0       0        0
    4          0       0        0
    5          1       0        1
    6          0       0        0
    7          0       0        0
    8          0       0        0
    9          0       0        0
   10          0       0        0
   11          0       1        1
   12          1       1        1
```

My code :

```
import csv
import os

f = open('file2', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')   
reader = list(reader)
f1 = open('file1', 'r')
reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=';')
next(reader1)
reader1 = list(reader1)


for line1 in reader1:
    for line in reader:
        if line1[0] != line[0]:
            print(line1)
        else:
            print(line)
```

Comment: There are not valid CSV files: your header use "; " as a separator, the other lines use spaces.

Comment: there are everywhere ; delimiter but it was just an exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has two very nice functions to help you avoid a nested for loop and make the process more efficient:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', options='whatever makes your csvs load')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', options='whatever makes your csvs load')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Frame_Nr')
```

Optionally, if you want the resulting `DataFrame` sorted by `Frame_Nr`, chain a `.sort_values('Frame_Nr')` to the last line

To explain the code snippet: `pd.concat` concatenates both DataFrames so that you first have all rows from file 1 and after that all rows from file 2, the `drop_duplicates` after that removes all rows with duplicate values in `Frame_Nr`, keeping the first. Since `file1` was the first file in the concatenation, all lines from that file are kept and lines from `file2` are only retained if they have a frame number that was not in `file1`. Optionally, the `sort_values` will sort the DataFrame by the frame number column

Comment: can you please explain me a little bit the code, it works but idk why :))

Comment: `pd.concat` concatenates both DataFrames so that you first have all rows in file 1 and after that all rows from file 2, the `drop_duplicates` after that removes all rows with duplicate values in `Frame_Nr`, keeping the first. Since `file1` was the first file in the concatenation, all lines from that file are kept and lines from `file2` are only retained if they have a frame number that was not in `file1`

Comment: I'll edit the description into my answer for easier reference

Comment: one last question :D  before my data i have a number equal wth frame nr how i can remove this?

Comment: That is Pandas' default index. You can choose `index=False` when calling `df.to_csv()` if you don't want the index saved to a file, but as long as your data is in a DataFrame, you'll have to "cope" with it. You may also want to choose to make `Frame_Nr` your index, in which case you can use `df.set_index('Frame_Nr')`

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

df=pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Frame_Nr;').sort_values("Frame_Nr;")
```